# How do you play a sound/buffer in reverse with AudioKit / AudioPlayer?

Tags: audiokit

I would like to playback buffered audio samples with variable speed, forward or reverse.
I'm aware of the `isReversed` attribute of `AudioPlayer` but am not succeeding in playing sounds in reverse.

Can anyone point me to an example or a hint?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via the `reverse` method of a buffer:

```
myBufferReversed = myBuffer.reverse()
```

Then, a player instance can be set to use `myBufferReversed` instead.

I believe but have not confirmed that this can also be achieved by setting the `isReversed` attribute to `true` as described on this wiki page:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/wiki/AudioPlayer